# Convert one line json into multiple lines to write to a file (Ruby)

Tags: json, ruby

I've run into a situation where I'm retrieving a json string in ruby, but I'm attempting to write it to a file structured like your usual json file (for example:

```
{
    "top":{
        "mid1":"bot1", 
        "mid2":"bot2"
    }
}
```

However, the way the json string is structured is like so:

```
{"top":{"mid1":"bot1","mid2":"bot2"}}
```

I've seen other posts mention doing JSON.parse in order to get what I want, however that just causes it to look like this:

```
{"top"=>{"mid1"=>"bot1", "mid2"=>"bot2"}}
```

Is there a way that I can just convert the json string into what it looks like in the first code block above?

Comment: The two English words most commonly used in the industry for this are "pretty" and "tidy". Using those words should help you search for solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The first representation is JSON. The decoded version is Ruby's internal representation. If you want to go back to JSON, `JSON.dump(...)` will reconvert it.

Keep in mind this is just presentation. The data is the same.

You may be interested in the [`pp` method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/PP.html) as that produces nice, structured debugging output.